# Google Drive Account Chooser Dialog won't cancel

Tags: android, dialog, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am using google drive on android to backup files. Backup is working fine. However when I am presented with the dialog to choose an account to back up to, if I hit "Cancel" the dialog just closes and reappears. It gets caught in a loop and I am forced to choose an account. While debugging the code I see that onConnectionFailed() is called everytime I hit cancel. SIGN_IN_REQUIRED is the resolution code passed to it and so the dialog gets called again.

How can I break out of this loop and allow the user to cancel? Has anybody else had this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by editing my onActivityResult method.

Previously I had:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}
```

I changed this so that if there was no resolution (which is what happens when cancel is clicked), I just finish the activity hosting the dialog:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    else {

      finish();
    }
}
```

So now the activity ends if the user clicks cancel, which is fine for my purposes.